# Starting a workflow in another workflow

Tags: workflow, email

I'm seeing a lot of Can't be done answers, but they are from years ago so I thought I would ask again..

I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2013.  I have a workflow that takes files from one library and moves it to one of 10 other libraries based on the file name.  My problem is that I want a workflow that sends out an email when a files lands in one of the secondary libraries.  I can't get the second "email" work flow to fire .  I works, because when i drag and drop a file in the secondary library the email fires off.  It just will not fire when a workflow copies a file to it...

So... File in lib "A" is moved via workflow"A".  Once in lib "B" workflow "B" should send an email, workflow B is not starting.   Any ideas?  thanks all

Comment: I started workflow in TimerJob but only WF2010